# Symfony same code, different server, no field or assocation

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two servers (on locally and one production). They have the same settings. The only thing I update when I want my new code to go to production is the src folder. So this folder is exactly the same when I push a release.

On my local server the new column in my entity/table works, and can be created, updated, etc. But on my production environment, this new column isn't noticed or even selected by doctrine.

The new column is in my database (both production and local), is in my `entity.php` file, in my `entity.orm.yml` file.

I did the `app/console cache:clear` option. Both dev and prod and on both servers.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: auto_mapping may not be set to true in config.yml

Comment: are your local and production servers both running in 'prod' mode? What output do you get if you run 'app/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql'?

Comment: Did you update the proxies?

Comment: @pcm auto mapping is set to true.

Comment: @GuillemoMansilla the values are written in the proxy files, so I guess they're updated.

Comment: @redbirdo ah, this is weird. It says ALTER TABLE lessonbook DROP ical, DROP paid_until; which are the two new columns. Why would symfony wants to drop them?

Comment: @AngeloA I'd say it suggests your production code is not up to date - your entity.orm.yml file on production doesn't contain those new columns.

Comment: @redbirdo, I just checked. They're both in my .orm.yml file

Comment: @AngeloA If doctrine doesn't see those fields for a schema update it won't see them when the app is running. The most typical reasons would be that the entity.orm.yml file on production does not match the one on the local server or that the cache has not flushed. The other time I've seen this issue is an error in the orm.yml but then it wouldn't work on either server.

Comment: Can you post the section of the ORM config for the new fields? Are both the servers running on the same OS?

Comment: @PaulSaunders fixed it! Posting the solution below. Took me a week to discover this.

Comment: @AngeloA great, I'm interested to see it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally found the solution.

Because I didn't use metadata cache on the local server, but I did on my production server, it saved my mapping information. That's why doctrine didn't knew I had new columns. The solution was to clear the metadata cache using:

`php bin/console doctrine:cache:clear-metadata`

After that I run `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` and I got the new columns.